# MongoTemplate findAndModify get updated document count

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using MongoTemplate to implement a method that can **update multiple documents according to the query, and return the updated document count**.

When I was using MySQL, update method usually return the updated data count as default, so I'm wondering how can I get the same thing in mongo?

Also, using the **findAndModify** because I want the function to be multi-thread-safe.

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

findAndModify updates only one document instead in MongoTemplate we have updateMulti which updates multiple document and return a writeResult which can tell you how many documents were updated

```
/**
 * finds the elements based on query and modifies it
 * 
 * @param query
 * @param update
 * @param clazz
 * @return
 * @throws MeowException
 */
protected <T> WriteResult modifyAll(final Query query, final Update update, final Class<T> clazz) throws MeowException{
    try{
        return getMongoTemplate().updateMulti(query, update, clazz);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw new MeowException(ex).withParam("query", query).withParam("update", update).withParam("class", clazz).logToFile("Exception in modifyAll");
    }
}
```

This can be called as

```
WriteResult result = modifyAll(query, update, Kitten.class);
logger.error("document updated count :"+result.getN());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: instead of just getting the count, do we have to actually get a list of all those records, or even a field of all the updated records?